# Why are emergency service professionals exempt from CA prohibitions on texting while driving?

Tags: united-states, law, us-state-laws, state-legislatures, california

When I first read the article headlined "[Police Officer Will Not Be Charged For Killing Napster Exec While Texting And Driving — Because It's Apparently OK For Police To Do That](http://www.businessinsider.com/police-officer-will-not-be-charged-in-killing-of-napster-executive-2014-8)" I expected it would be a somewhat cynical view discussing how police are above the law in practice, etc.

However, when reading the [official document where this result was determined](https://www.scribd.com/doc/237940150/Official-document-Deputy-won-t-be-charged-in-death-of-Calabasas-bicyclist-Milton-Olin), I saw the explicit carve-out cited, from [CA Vehicle Code 23123.5](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=VEH&sectionNum=23123.5.), CA's law against texting while driving.  Section (e):

> This section does not apply to an emergency services professional using an electronic wireless communications device while operating an authorized emergency vehicle, as defined in Section 165, in the course and scope of his or her duties.

Since this texting-while-driving death was caused by a deputy officer in the performance of his official duties, it falls under this exception and makes what the officer did legal.  **Why was this exemption specifically written in to the law?**  Why did the legislature choose to make it legal for an officer to text while driving, even if that kills somebody, while that's prohibited for others?

This law was added in [2007-2008 SB28 Sec. 2](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/displayCodeAndBill.xhtml?sectionNum=23123.5.&billVersionSectionId=3451517&lawCode=VEH). (Parts of it other than (e) were [amended in 2011-2012 AB1536 Sec. 1](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/displayCodeAndBill.xhtml?sectionNum=23123.5.&billVersionSectionId=3726786&lawCode=VEH).) The bill that added the law can be found [here](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/billTextClient.xhtml?bill_id=200720080SB28). The votes are listed [here](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/billVotesClient.xhtml?bill_id=200720080SB28), indicating passage by a pretty good sized majority.

The bill digest does not mention the exemption for emergency services professionals, nor does the [fact sheet](http://www.senatorsimitian.com/images/uploads/SB_28_Fact_Sheet_on_letter_head.doc) or [letter to the Governor](http://www.senatorsimitian.com/images/uploads/Letter_to_Governor_SB_28.doc) available from the [sponsor's web page for the bill](http://www.senatorsimitian.com/entry/sb_0028_texting_while_driving_prohibition/).  Summaries in [analyses of the bill](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/billAnalysisClient.xhtml?bill_id=200720080SB28) do list the exclusion but don't explain why or where it comes from, other than indicating there's also an exemption in previously existing law regarding voice calls. 
*(Note: "08/01/08- Senate Floor Analyses" appears to be about Senate Joint Resolution 28 rather than Senate Bill 28; 07/06/07 and earlier analyses seems to be about RFID licenses instead)*.

I found an additional bill history system [here](http://www.leginfo.ca.gov/cgi-bin/postquery?bill_number=sb_28&sess=0708&house=S&author=simitian) but it doesn't seem to add new information.  I could not find debate records that might explain why this exclusion is in there which might help *answer* the question, but I hope I've demonstrated sufficient research here for it to be a good *asking* of the question.

---

*If the same exception exists in another jurisdiction and you're able to explain why it exists for that one instead, that's still a welcome answer (please just be clear about the jurisdiction).*

Comment: First, this one is more fit for law.stackexchange.com than here. OTOH, if you read the article it explains rather well that the PO was not using WhatsApp or whatever, he was using a PD provided computer to do PD things. Due to the nature of PD things, some of them may be urgent enough that need to access the PD information systems, so a blanket ban could be counterproducent (`police officers are expected to respond quickly to messages from colleagues`). Note that this does not mean that the PO or the PD have no responsability, it means that the criminal charges have been dropped.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs to law.stackexchange.com

Comment: I disagree that this fits on Law.SE.  The question isn't why the law has this effect, but why the law was written that way.  That would be off-topic on Law, but is on-topic here as the law was written by politicians.

Comment: Is the law actually giving special treatment to police officers? Is it illegal for a civilian to use a laptop while driving?

Comment: I'm leaving this question open.  It is perfectly possible for a question to be on-topic at 2 stack exchanges at once.

Comment: The question that would be on-topic at Law.SE is the one answered by "because of this exception at CA Vehicle Code 23123.5(e)" and/or by quoting analysis from the prosecutor's document, linked to above.  This question is here on Politics because it's asking about how that exception got into the bill and what aspects of the political process produced that result, without asking about what the law is or how it applies.

Comment: Insofar as the *creation* of the vehicle code is a political activity, performed either by the legislature or the state executive this is an on-topic question. The debate surrounding the creation of the law is where we would find any justification, should the justification exist—it is also possible it just slipped in and was never considered—and that is a political issue. The way this would be a strictly legal issue is if the only justification occurred more in the courts, (i.e. it was a ruling). As @SamIam noted, sometimes questions are on topic at 2 SEs.

Comment: @TTT yes, it is.  I even linked to/summarized "[CA Vehicle Code 23123.5](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=VEH&sectionNum=23123.5.), CA's law against texting while driving."  You can see that section (e) is an exemption carving a special privilege out of a rule that makes such activities illegal unless the exemption applies.

Comment: @WBT - OK, I agree. However, the officer wasn't texting on his cell phone, he was using the Mobile Data Terminal which, if compared to a civilian, would be more like typing in your GPS coordinates into your car's touchscreen while driving.

Comment: @TTT this was a text-based communication to another human, so the e-mail analogy is more fitting, and that's what's prohibited by the law unless the exemption applies.  This is not a law about inputting into GPS devices, it's about text-based communications, and the question is about where the exemption came from.

Comment: @WBT - good point. Even though I don't see much difference in the amount of distraction between the two, you're right that it applies just to text-based communications. I can guess why the exemption exists: civilians do not *need* to make text based communications while driving, it is merely a convenience. However, emergency personnel could *need* to as a normal course of their duties, as lives may be at risk. Perhaps the exception would be better if it only allowed emergency personnel to use it if it truly is an emergency, rather than a blanket waiver.

Comment: @TTT There are a lot of civilians who have been told of the dangers of texting while driving, and even believe that it's dangerous, but do it anyway because they believe they *need* to make those text-based communications while driving, and would defend that "*need*" if pressed to do so.  And quite often, lives **are** at risk, whether the person doing the texting-while-driving is an emergency services professional or not.

Comment: @WBT - I agree many people believe it, and I'd say "tell it to the judge". I agree that it's possible that lives are at risk when it's a civilian texting, but I disagree that it's "quite often". In fact I believe it's extremely rare that someone *must* text while driving. If you can't pull over because you are being chased by someone who wants to kill you AND you can't call someone because your phone's microphone is broken so you must send a text message instead, then I'd bet in that case the judge would let it slide.

Comment: @TTT the "quite often" sentence covers both risks that would be larger if the text-based communications did not occur (which is how you read it) AND risks that would be larger if the text-based communications did occur [while the person was driving] (which is the motivation for CA Vehicle Code 23123.5).

Comment: @WBT - I didn't follow your last comment. Can you give an example of where lives would be at risk and texting would be necessary to mitigate that risk? (Perhaps we should move this to chat...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40061/discussion-between-wbt-and-ttt).

Answer (score 10):

The section of the law you quote already sort of has the answer:

> does not apply to an emergency services professional [..] in the course and scope of his or her duties.

While it's not explicit, we can infer that emergency service personal sometimes need to use these devices "in the course and scope of his or her duties".

In this specific case, it seems that the message was sent as part of the duties:

> Wood drifted into the bicycle lane while typing a reply to a colleague who wanted to know whether any other officers were required to attend a fire reported at a high school he had just left.

Note that he wasn't "texting", but using his [Mobile Digital Computer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_jQvOHzrNA), which is basically just a computer built in to the police car. They've been around since the 80s (from before the term "laptop" became popular), so police have been "texting and driving" since then.

Arguably, he should not have done this while driving; although this depends on the circumstances. Perhaps he was driving on the way to an urgent(-ish) call? The article offers no details on this, but [another article](http://valleywag.gawker.com/la-sheriffs-deputy-who-killed-former-napster-exec-wont-1628033542) reports:

> prosecutors said it was "reasonable" that Wood would have felt that an immediate response was necessary so that a Calabasas deputy wouldn't unnecessarily respond to [a fire call].

Officers [do get training on this](http://www.dailynews.com/general-news/20140827/in-calabasas-death-of-cyclist-milton-olin-no-charges-against-typing-deputy), apparently:

> In mobile digital competency tests, employees are also reminded “to use caution” while operating an MDC and that “distracted driving is inherently unsafe,” according to training documents provided by the Sheriff’s Department.

Comment: I'll add that this law as stated has nothing to do specifically with texting or even phones in general. As such, the exception is required as ALL first responders use walkies or CB or similar to communicate with dispatch. Without said exception this would effectively outlaw all police, EMTs, firefighters, etc... I'll also add that I once smoked a fat piece of carpet lint thinking it was a nug that rolled out of my bag. You are not alone.